# How to do CakePHP validation before form data is sent as Ajax request?

Tags: jquery, ajax, validation, cakephp, model

I would like to do standard CakePHP model validation *before* form is sent to the server via Ajax request. When there will be some validation errors, I would like to show them in standard way how are errors displayed and cancel Ajax request, if there is no error, do the request.

I have this JavaScript code to do an Ajax request and display the result in Bootstrap modal window:

```
$('#btn_submit_preview').click(function (event) {
        var formData = $("#OfferAddForm").serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/offers/preview/",
            data: formData,
            success: function (data) {
                $('#modal_body_div').html(data);
                $('#myModal').modal('show');
            }
        });
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: What are you using for client side validation?
jQuery Validator or something else

Answer (score 0):

Use the [jQuery Validation Plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation) and please try something like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#OfferAddForm').validate({ // initialize the plugin
        // your rules and options,
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            var formData = $("#OfferAddForm").serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/offers/preview/",
        data: formData,
        success: function (data) {
            $('#modal_body_div').html(data);
            $('#myModal').modal('show');
        }
    });
    event.preventDefault();
    return false; // blocks redirect after submission via ajax
        }
    });

});
```